# Line breaks in condition of MS Word formula editor

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using a formula that has a rather long condition which does not fit to the page. [Please have a look at this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxjw1.png)

However, instead of using a line break, Word just continues the formula beyond the page. Is there a way to make Word use an intelligent line break or introducing one manually without introducing a new line, which will destroy the rest of the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click at any blank area within the equation, where breaking will not disturb the essence of the equation, select Insert manual break.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put the entire formula in a cell of a table with invisible borders. Worked for me when I was writing longer formulas.

Comment: I tried putting it into a table, but it just goes behind the other cells ...

Comment: I did that with my formulas and it worked. Hmmm...